# Angular show pop-up after receiving response from all APIs called

Tags: angular, typescript, callback, angular6, alert

I am using an angular 6 application where users can purchase products. If the user selects a product and press **Pay Now** button the following API gets called.

```
doPay() {
        this.http.post('https://testpayment?action=payproduct', params, options).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log("Cart payment done.", data);
                this.getProductList(); // API call
                this.getUserDetails(); // API call
                var callback = () => {
                    // Make sure getProductList and getUserDetails APIs got executed and response received
                    // Perform redirection here
                };
                Globals.alert("You have successfully purchased product","OK", callback);
            },
            error => {
                console.error("Cart payment error!", error);
            }
        );
    }
```

Here, I am showing alert/pop message if payproduct is success and there is a callback for alert.

This callback decides where to redirect page after payment. Inside this callback I want to execute few code after getProductList and getUserDetails response received.

Can anyone please guide me how to make sure getProductList and getUserDetails response received so that I can make page redirection based on that

```
getProductList()
{
   this.http.get('some_url).subscribe(
    data => {
       console.log("Product list:", data);
       this.my_products = data;  
       for (var i in this.my_products) {  
         this.getPurchasedItem(this.my_products[i].Id);  
       }  
     }  
    )  
}
```

```
getPurchasedItem(id) {
        this.http.get('some_url').subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log("Item:", data);
                for (let i=0; i< this.my_products.length; i++) {
                    if (this.my_products[i].ItemCode == data['ItemCode']){
                        this.my_products[i] = data;
                    }
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.error("error!", error);
            }
        );
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assume `this.getProductList();` is defined as:

```
getProductList()
{
  return this.http.post("some_url",params,options);
}
```

and `this.getUserDetails();` is defined as:

```
getUserDetails()
{
  return this.http.post("some_url",params,options);
}
```

then you can make sure these API calls are executed by using subscribe, like:

```
doPay() {
        this.http.post('https://testpayment?action=payproduct', params, options).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log("Cart payment done.", data);
                this.getProductList().subscribe(dat=>{
                   this.getUserDetails().subscribe(da=>{
                      var callback = () => {
                      // Perform redirection here
                      };
                      Globals.alert("You have successfully purchased product","OK", callback);
                   },er=>console.log(er));
                },err=>console.log(err));
            },
            error => {
                console.error("Cart payment error!", error);
            }
        );
    }
```

this way the redirection happens only when both the API calls are executed.

Comment: In my case, there is another API call inside getProductDetails() so more nesting. Basically, I want to manipulate few variables like this.my_products and perform redirection using that. I have update my question

Comment: Is there any way where I can wait for few seconds to complere getProductList() and
 getUserDetails() API calls and after that, alert() can be executed.

Comment: More nesting is quite confusing and code readability will not be easy

Comment: Returning your API call to subscribe it later and nesting within is the best approach I can think of since it makes sure that the API calls are executed. But to wait for a few seconds you may use the `setTimeout`.                                                                                            `setTimeout(()=>{//your requirements},1000);` waits for one second to execute your requirements